# Why Arent Breakpoints Working In Web Application Project

Tags: asp.net

My company gave me a web application project and I went to debug it and set some breakpoints and they dont fire. I am using `Response.Write` all over the place to debug. Anyone know what maybe going on?

I am running the application off my localhost I was pushing F5, but since the breakpoints dont hit by making changes and adding Response.Write statements and clicking save then refreshing my browser I get the changes for whatever reason.

Hovering over the breakpoint it says "The breakpoint will not currently be hit the source code differs from the original version"

Another tidbit is I created a new web application project and created a breakpoint and it works, its only specific to this application it seems like, but dont know what it could be?

Comment: We are going to need more information than that. How is your web application set up? Are you running the web app on your local machine?  How are you attempting to debug the application (i.e. are you pressing F5 in VS)?

Comment: Visual Studio Version, Framework, language? What does VS say when you hover your breakpoints?

Comment: Do you run the application in IIS or in the built-in Visual Studio web server?

Comment: @Xavier Ran it in Visual Studio built in web server

Comment: have you tried to delete .suo file?

Comment: @adt there is no .suo for this in the project directory that I can see

Comment: Visual Studio will save breakpoint information in the solution .suo file, you may close the Visual Studio and delete the .suo file to clear the cache. suo file is located whereever your sln file. if these dont work. you can try deleting folder in asp.net temporay files, clean solution and make sure you are building in debug mode. and one more thing when you put break point. red circles are filled or not?

Comment: Where is the ASP.Net Temp Files for the 3.5 framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hovering over the breakpoint it says "The breakpoint will not currently be hit the source code differs from the original version"

Try this:

- Close Visual Studio and make sure any instances of ASP.NET development server are closed as well
- Delete everything from "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files" (where v4.0.30319 is the version of your .NET Framework)

Comment: Im using framework 3.5 and I dont see the Temporary ASP.NET Files in that directory

Comment: Have a look here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/vbide/thread/b1725aa1-c7d7-4be4-990f-95d5b77c2c66 and http://forums.asp.net/t/372106.aspx/1?Breakpoints+are+not+working+in+Visual+Studio+net

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after reading the comments posted on your question I was making the following assumptions.

- You are running using the built in VS development server
- You are compiling in debug mode
- You've set debugging true in your web.config

I've seen this problem before and for me it's been resolved by restarting Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely need more info, but I would check that your are building with debugging symbols to cover the dumb stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are running on IIS on the same machine that you have visual studio installed:

- Have you attached to the application pool process
- Is you code the same as what is deploy? (Is the latest version deployed)
- Are you logged in as administrator?
- Are you running visual studio as administrator?

Just to make sure, you are running in debug mode?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem a while ago as well, instead of using response.write, you could try outputting the data to a label control's text value instead to see the values of your code.

It's a bit of a sloppy work around, but I couldn't figure out why that one particular project I was working on didn't let me debug it.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is, for me, mostly caused by a mismatch of the loaded dll files (symbols) by webserver, and those that the project are pointing to when you try to breakpoint. It's different files. I have located different causes. One could be a simple hang-up by webdev instans (force shutdown. But also that there occur some kind of mismatch if you got different compilation methods between project within same solution as the web project.

This desc may not be your exact problem, but perhaps it will lead you into right direction. I find this often being a dirty unlogic error that just are irritating (but also completely fixable without data loss or reconfiguring, when u understand the trick).

Comment: I will also state that working around this with debug.write or something will probably cause you only see the original code. If you make changes, it will not appear.

Comment: ....and if you don't find out the rest, u can try check this above. You can also try delete (or more preferrable in your case) move out all dll files (from the /bin directories) and recompile the whole project. If you use external dll' copy them back. If you mix .net 3.5 and .net 4.0 assemblies (for example) error like this are ocurring.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and it turned out only Internet Explorer works with debugging and breakpoints. To avoid having IE as my default browser, I changed the launch settings in the .Web project to run IE with the path as command line parameters.