# ASP.NET Application misses the Breakpoints

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I'm facing a severe problem - my ASP application doesn't see the Breakpoints. 
I've read this [Why Arent Breakpoints Working In Web Application Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187110/why-arent-breakpoints-working-in-web-application-project). But it didn't help. 
I'm using VS2010 and the page is loaded in IE.

Here's my web.config file

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices"
         connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <system.web>
    <siteMap enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add siteMapFile="Web.sitemap" name="AspNetXmlSiteMapProvider" type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider" securityTrimmingEnabled="true"/>
      </providers>
    </siteMap>

    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />

    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>

    <membership>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices"
             enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false"
             maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
             applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>

    <profile>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </profile>

    <roleManager enabled="false">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
        <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>

  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
     <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>


</configuration>
```

I start my application simply clicking F5 in VisualStudio.
Does anybody know what the mistake is, please?

This is my Login.aspx.cs

```
public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RegisterHyperLink.NavigateUrl = "Register.aspx?ReturnUrl=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]);
    }

    protected void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var userNameTextBox = LoginUser.FindControl("UserName") as TextBox;
        var passwordTextBox = LoginUser.FindControl("Password") as TextBox;
        if (userNameTextBox != null && passwordTextBox != null)
        {
            bool succes = UserDAL.Login(userNameTextBox.Text, passwordTextBox.Text);
            if (succes == true)
                Server.Transfer("~/Account/Succes.aspx");
        }
    }
}
```

And here's its interface.

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
<center>
    <p>
        Введите имя пользователя и пароль.
        <asp:HyperLink ID="RegisterHyperLink" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">Register</asp:HyperLink> если у вас нет учетной записи.
    </p>
    <asp:Login ID="LoginUser" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" RenderOuterTable="false">
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <span class="failureNotification">
                <asp:Literal ID="FailureText" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
            </span>
            <asp:ValidationSummary ID="LoginUserValidationSummary" runat="server" CssClass="failureNotification" 
                 ValidationGroup="LoginUserValidationGroup"/>
            <div class="accountInfo">
                <fieldset class="login">
                    <legend>text</legend>
                    <p>
                        <asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName">Login:</asp:Label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server" CssClass="textEntry"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="UserNameRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="UserName" 
                             CssClass="failureNotification" ErrorMessage="" ToolTip="" 
                             ValidationGroup="LoginUserValidationGroup">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <asp:Label ID="PasswordLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Password">Password:</asp:Label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" CssClass="passwordEntry" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="PasswordRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Password" 
                             CssClass="failureNotification" ErrorMessage="" ToolTip="" 
                             ValidationGroup="LoginUserValidationGroup">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </p>
                </fieldset>
                <p class="submitButton">
                    <asp:Button ID="LoginButton" runat="server" CommandName="Login" Text="Выполнить вход" ValidationGroup="LoginUserValidationGroup"/>
                </p>
            </div>
        </LayoutTemplate>
    </asp:Login>
</center>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Are you running the project in debug or release mode?

Comment: @LeviBotelho, the application is in Debug mode

Comment: Do any breakpoints work (for example at the very start of the application) or none at all?

Comment: @LeviBotelho Oh, thanks you've hit the point I forgot to check... Yeah, the breakpoints in the Page_Load section work, but in the button section it doesn't. I'll print the button code bellow

Comment: If you `Start Debugging` and hover over the breakpoint for the button code in the code-behind, what does the debugger say?  There should be a tooltip that shows when you hover over a breakpoint indicating *why* it's not loaded. That message has a good amount of bearing on the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add an `OnClick="LoginButton_Click"` attribute to your `<asp:Button...>` item to hook the button to the event.

[Read more here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclick.aspx), or use [`CommandName / CommandArgument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.commandname.aspx).

You are doing a bit of both and that is why it is not working as you expect.